# SharePoint Designer Workflow Error: Validation Failed PropertyType Doesn't match Target Type

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I am using SharePoint Designer 2013 for a SharePoint 365 site, and am using the built-in SP2010 'Update item in ' workflow to updates an item in List A to the same item in List B.

This workflow was working perfectly until, today, I received the below error.

> (0, 0) Activity 'ID1690' validation failed: Path resolved to
>   Referenced activity Property 'ReturnValue' whose PropertyType
>   'System.Double' does not match with the Target Type 'System.String'.)

Note that the ID error has also appeared as 'ID1548' but the details are the same.

From what I gather, one of the columns in List A and List B don't match up from a data type perspective (i.e. float/long vs. string) but I have check all of my columns/fields and nothing has helped.

At the very least, how can I check which columns have a data type of System.Double?

Let me know if you need more details.

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The ID field used to identify the item between List A and List B had different formats between the two lists. After refreshing SP Designer, the workflow worked again.